# How to disallow people to be employee on my company on LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin

I created a company profile on LinkedIn. Some people who work *with* us say they worked *at* this company. Is there a way for company profile admins on LinkedIn to **get requests when people say they worked at this company?** And to be able to **accept/reject these requests?**

Note: I plan to create a second company profile for these people to which they can connect and then to keep the original company clean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no way to make your company 'private' so to speak on LinkedIn. You can only make a group private unfortunately.